# How to check if element is present with protractor?

Tags: angular, protractor

I wrote the following protractor test for an Angular2 app:

```
describe('Puppet container', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    browser.get('/#/puppet');
  });

  it('should display puppet summary', () => {
    browser.wait($('puppet-summary').isPresent, 1000);

    const subject = $('puppet-summary').isDisplayed();
    const result = true;

    expect(subject).toEqual(result);
  });

});
```

It keeps failing with the following reason: `Failed: Cannot read property 'parentElementArrayFinder' of undefined`

Can anybody tell me why I'm getting this error? I have a page which only shows the `<puppet-summary>` element when the data from the backend is loaded. That's why I'm checking for it to be present (it only becomes present after half a second or so). To show it only if there is data to display, I'm using the following HTML code:

```
<div *ngIf="puppetMasters.length">
    <puppet-summary></puppet-summary>
</div>
```

`puppetMasters` is an array which gets filled as soon as the data from the backend is loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `browser.wait($('puppet-summary').isPresent, 1000);`

The "wait for an element to be present" should be done via the built-in  [`presenceOf` Expected Condition](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elm = $('puppet-summary');
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 1000);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, @alecxe!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have a look into this [site](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api) to find all element locators, conditions, ...
And for element is present you can see this example : 
[element(locator).isPresent](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below function . it will wait until the given html object is present.

```
browser.wait(function() {
    return element(by.css("#edudrop1")).isPresent()});
```

Answer (score -1):

hope it helps )

```
.isPresent() vs .isPresent
```

Comment: It's not that, `browser.wait()` expect a "function" as a first argument which it would call contuniosly until the condition evaluates to true or the timeout is reached.

Comment: `browser.wait($('puppet-summary').isPresent(), 1000);`

Comment: In other words, `$('puppet-summary').isPresent()` is not a function - it is a result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @MichalSviha. I was following this blog post: http://docsplendid.com/archives/209 and I must agree with @alecxe. The first argument of `browser.wait()` must be a function.